How to know if an Azure Deployment Swap with Preview has restarted instances
We need know if an Azure Deployment Swap with Preview has restarted instances before we complete the swap. We have application initialization in place, but we still get 500 errors if we complete the swap before all the instances have restarted and are warmed up.
We have also added these two App Settings on each Deployment slot to act as a guardrail as it prevents swapping unless instances are 200 ok/online... but this requires us to start the swap with preview over again if we swap before the instances are warmed up (because we don't know if they are).
If we try a straight swap, it fails quickly. This has led us to just use a long wait before swapping and hoping all instances are back online (we have 12). Here is the source where we found the following settings: https://ruslany.net/2019/06/azure-app-service-deployment-slots-tips-and-tricks/
WEBSITE_SWAP_WARMUP_PING_PATH: The path to make the warm up request to. Set this to a URL path that begins with a slash as the value. For example, “/warmup.php”. The default value is /.
WEBSITE_SWAP_WARMUP_PING_STATUSES:Expected HTTP response codes for the warm-up operation. Set this to a comma-separated list of HTTP status codes. For example: “200,202” . If the returned status code is not in the list, the swap operation will not complete. By default, all response codes are valid.
Ideally, this should be an automated process (we use Azure DevOps) where we swap with preview and there is some sort of hook we can call to see if all instances have restarted and are warmed up/ready for swap completion.
